# Connect 100Mbit GMAC to a 1Gbit GMAC VSC8211

Tags: phy, networking, mac

I would like to connect a 100Mbit GMAC on the SAMe70 with a 1000BASE-SX Switch. What will happen if I connect VSC8211 to this device and then attach a 1000BASE-SX Switch?

Will the Autoneg on the Physical Layer make a 1000Bit connection but the SAMe70 MAC will adjust the data speed to 100Mbit with Flow-control (The switch keeps sending at 1000MBit but Flow control adjust the dataspeed, similiar to window size in TCP-connection) ? I know that 1000BASE-SX use Autoneg but can only use 1000BASE-SX as an option.

So my question is:

What will happen with the traffic between the SAMe70 and the VSC8211?

If the switch sends 1000Mbit and the MAC on SAMe70 transmit a Pause/Flow-control. The PHY is capable of 1000Mbit but the mac can only handle 100Mbit. Will it work but only at a throughput of 100Mbit or will it be total error?

[image]